# What determines my character's maximum Health and Mana?

Tags: kingdoms-of-amalur-reckoning

As I level up, I'm gaining increases to both my maximum health and my maximum mana.  These don't seem to be increasing equally, however, as I'm seeing my maximum mana increase faster than my total health.

What factors are involved in determining my character's maximum health and mana?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

I was playing around with this [Ability Calculator](http://amalurfoundry.com/calculator) (which is a great resource in and of itself!), and I noticed that it also displays maximum health and mana, and they seem to increase as my abilities increase.

With a bit of poking, I think I determined that the formula is:

```
health = round(50 + might_points*4/3 + finesse_points + sorcery_points*2/3)
mana = round(50 + might_points*2/3 + finesse_points + sorcery_points*4/3)
```

Therefore, if you focus on solely Sorcery abilities, your mana will increase 2x faster than your health, and vice versa for Might.  Finesse points increase both equally.

At level 40, your estimated maximum "base" health/mana (counting only health/mana gained from ability point increases) would be:

- 214 Mana for all points in Sorcery (leaving you with 132 health)
- 214 Health for all points in Might (leaving you with 132 mana)
- 173 Health and 173 mana for all points in Finesse

You can experiment with other combinations using the ability calculator I linked above, this is just a general reference as to what focusing on one tree to the exclusion of others might give you health and mana-wise.

Comment: This is a very interesting observation, did you make this formula up or find it somewhere?

Comment: I based it on observations from the ability calculator I linked.  By maxing out each tree, comparing that against the base and using the number of total skill points, I worked out these formulas.

Comment: Suddenly all those items with `+5 health` seem a much better deal.

Comment: I'll have to look at that calculator, I just picked up the game like 2 days ago and have had little time for it. So basically you will be leveling dead even if you're only invested into the Finess tree, but once you diverge you're going to start seeing a change?

Comment: Do you know if the # of skill points used in the calculation includes bonuses given from gear, fates, or potions?

Comment: @Rachel The answer to "gear" at least is no - I've got a set that gives me +2 to finesse abilities, and equipping it does not appear to change my max health or mana.

Comment: @agent86 Oh so your Health/Mana is a calculated value at any given time based on this formula? I don't know why but I thought you were talking about the calculation it used to permanently add to your HP/Mana on level up.

Comment: @Rachel, I believe these values are recalculated any time you apply ability points - ie, you level up or you respec your abilities.